# Why is Python not found by VS Code but found in the VS Code integrated terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was trying learning about logging in python for the first time today. I discovered when i tried running my code from VS Code, I received this error message

`/bin/sh: 1: python: not found` however when I run the code directly from my terminal, I get the expected result. I need help to figure out the reason for the error message when I run the code directly from VSCode.

Comment: are you using the Code Runner extension? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14229

Answer (score 0):

Python Interpreter to be set up. Many ways mentioned in the vs code documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments, here easiest would be to open command palette and search for python interpreter and there you can enter the path of python/python3 installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interperter"** to choose the python interpreter.

You can also click the button in the lower right.

[image]

Comment: I've done this several times, still getting the same error message. @MingJie-MSFT

Comment: @Oluwasube How did you run the file? Did you use code-runner extension?

Comment: Yes i used the code runner extension

Comment: @Oluwasube You can use **Run Python File** button which is provided by python extension instead of **Run Code** then retry.

Comment: I stopped trying to fix it. i noticed the issue comes up occassionally. sometimes it works fine and other times it doesn't. I'm using my terminal to debug code which is just fine. Thanks for your input @MingJie-MSFT

Answer (score -1):

The error message you are receiving indicates that the "python" executable is not found in the PATH environment variable of the terminal you are using from within Visual Studio Code.

Add the location of the Python executable to the PATH environment variable in your terminal.

Specify the full path to the Python executable in your Visual Studio Code terminal.

You can find the full path to the Python executable by running the command "which python" in your terminal.

Comment: But op said that running in the terminal can get correct output, which is independent of environment variables.

Comment: Rodolfo, just out of curiosity, did you get this from ChatGPT?