# /bin/sh: python: command not found -->My python program is not running in Vs code but running fine in terminal(I am using macos 12.6.1)

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

when try to run python program in vs code it keep showing "/bin/sh: python: command not found"

I have aliased python with python3

```
which python
aliased to /usr/bin/python3
```

```
which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

In terminal code is running fine but whenever I try to run using Vs code it throw error
`/bin/sh: python: command not found`

Comment: Aliases are only available in interactive shells (and only those that've run whatever shell init file you put the alias definition in). To have `python` work in non-shell contexts, you need a program (or symlink to one) named `python` in one of the directoryies in `$PATH` (and `$PATH` may be different in each process depending on what shell init files have/haven't been run).

Comment: How are you executing the code? Please add more details.

Comment: seems similar to / same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/75344761/11107541

Comment: are you using the Code Runner extension? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14229